A simple example of perverse sheaf
I'm calculating a simple example of the perverse sheaf:
Let $i:\mathbb{C}-\{0\} \to \mathbb{C}$ be the embedding, then I want show that shifted constant sheaf $Ri_{*}\mathbb{C}_{\mathbb{C}-\{0\}}[1]$ is a perverse sheaf.
So the first step is checking the dimension of support of cohomology sheaves. I was told that $0$-th cohomology sheaves will be $0$ except $H^{0}(Ri_{*}\mathbb{C}_{\mathbb{C}-\{0\}})=\mathbb{C}_{\mathbb{C}}$ and $H^{1}(Ri_{*}\mathbb{C}_{\mathbb{C}-\{0\}})=\mathbb{C}_0$ the skycreper sheaf support at the point $0$.
I know that I need to find a resolution for $\mathbb{C}_{\mathbb{C}-\{0\}}$ then apply $i_*$ and calculate the cohomology sheaves. My question is which resolution I should choose to get the result above? Or there is some simpler way to go?

Can you prove that $H^1(Ri_\mathbb{C}{\mathbb{C}-{0}})$ is a sheaf supported in $0$ ? As soon as you have this result, you know that $H^1(Ri\mathbb{C}{\mathbb{C}-{0}})$ is a skyscraper sheaf. To compute its rank, you can just use the fact that $H^1(Ri*\mathbb{C}_{\mathbb{C}-{0}})_0 = \varinjlim H^1(U - {0}, \mathbb{C})$ where $U$ runs through the neighborhoods of $0$.

@Roland, sorry, I don't know how to calculate this. I understand why there is a skyscraper sheaf, since the open subset $0\in U$, its preimage $i^{-1}(U)$ is homotopic to a circle, and therefore has $H^1(U)=\mathbb{C}$, which means $H^1$ is skyscraper sheaf supported at 0. But I don't know how to see this directly in complexes, resolutions etc.

You don't need any specific resolution, just the functoriality with the functor $i^{-1}$ and $x^{-1}$ (where $x:{0}\to \mathbb{C}$ is the inclusion.

And also that $R^if_*\mathcal{F}$ is the sheaf associated to $U\mapsto H^i(f^{-1}(U), \mathcal{F})$

@Roland Thank you, Roland. I basically understand your answer. The last statement I think is due to $R^if_∗F(U)=R\Gamma^i((f_*I)|U)=R\Gamma^{i}((I|{f^{−1}(U)})=H^n(f^{−1}(U),F)$,
where I is a resolution of F. Am I right? If F is arbitrary complex in derived category, is there a similar result? I guess the answer is yes.

What kind of result do you want to generalize ? In the derived category, you have the localization triangles $$ x_*x^!F \to F\to Ri_*F|U\to x*x^!F[1]$$ and $$ i_!F|U \to F\to  x*x^{-1}F\to i_!F|_U[1]$$7

@Roland I see. Thank you for your help!
